# Pandas series append returning NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having difficulty getting my dataframe data into their own timeseries. Here is my code so far:

```
data = pd.read_csv(s3_data_path, index_col=0, parse_dates=True, dtype="float64")
num_timeseries = data.shape[1]
print("This is the number of time series you're running:")
print(num_timeseries)

data_length = num_timeseries
t0 = data.index[0]
print("This is the beginning date:")
print(t0)
time_series=[]

for i in range(num_timeseries):
    index = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=t0, freq=freq, periods=data_length)
    time_series.append(pd.Series(data=data.iloc[:,i], index=index))

print(data.head(10))
print(time_series[0]
```

Whenever I run `print(data.head(10))` I see the following, which is what I expect:

[image]

However, my time_series object has values of NaN:

[image]

I don't quite understand what I'm missing to get the correct values in my time_series object. Thanks for the help!

Edit---
Whenever I remove the index=index out of my time_series.append the code generates my expected result (pictured below.) However, this creates an issue as no frequency is defined which is a requirement.

[image]

Comment: In the loop why do set a new index?

Comment: I didn't know a good way to specify the frequency of the index in the panda's read_csv() function

Comment: `index_col` sets the index to a `DatetimeIndex` as far as I can tell from your images. It would be great if you provided a minimal working example and specifically tell which data should be set to an index. The problem currently is, that the columns you extract in the for loop are indexed by the 0th column of your csv which does not match the index you define. Use `reindex` instead.

Comment: What exactly is the goal here? To break the dataframe into a list of dataframes that are just one column each?

Comment: I'm attempting to make time series all indexed by the same dates (Column 1 of my excel file), with the data of each column (Column 2 on) in the csv file as the values in those time series. This is for a ML script

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Edited the question to reflect, but the expected result is a number of time_series equivalent to the number of columns in the csv sheet. Each indexed by the dates.